# Updating Bokeh Choropleth As Standalone HTML with DateRangeSlider

Tags: python, pandas, slider, bokeh, geopandas

I'm a Python newbie with no JS experience learning Bokeh. I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of dated items by county all over the US and am trying to create a Bokeh choropleth that will update with a DateRangeSlider. From reading the documentation, in order to do this as a standalone HTML, I know I need some CustomJS but I don't even know where to begin updating my pandas data in JavaScript when the slider changes. Unfortunately, my work firewall won't let me use the Bokeh server so it must be an HTML standalone.

I am able to generate a simple static choropleth with the code below and a DateRangeSlider that is formatted the way I want but am completely stuck on how to make the DateRangeSlider control the Choropleth. As it is, I'm grouping the data by county in pandas before passing the geodataframe into a GeoJSONDataSource to Bokeh so Bokeh isn't even getting the date field to allow it to filter. I'm stuck on how to solve this.

Unfortunately, I can't provide the original data as the data is proprietary so I've used an example dataframe in the code below but worth noting that I'm dealing with about 3 million lines of data as opposed to the example of just a few.

I know this is a lot but any help on how I can get this working is much appreciated!!

````
```
import os
import csv
import bokeh
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from datetime import date

#Bokeh imports
from bokeh.io import show, output_file, curdoc, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import (ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, LogColorMapper, 
                          GMapOptions, WMTSTileSource, DateRangeSlider, 
                          BasicTickFormatter, LinearAxis, LogTicker, 
                          FixedTicker, FuncTickFormatter, CustomJS, ColorBar, 
                          CustomJSFilter, GeoJSONDataSource, LinearColorMapper)
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, WidgetBox, layout
from bokeh.palettes import brewer
from bokeh.plotting import figure, save, ColumnDataSource
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, MultiPoint, MultiPolygon
from shapely.prepared import prep
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider, Vendors


from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler

geosource = 1

output_notebook()

#group company_grouped_df into county, st
def make_df(start_date, end_date):
    df = company_grouped_df(start_date, end_date)
    df = df.groupby(['State', 'NAME']).sum().reset_index()
    return df

start='12/1/2019' 
end='12/8/2019'

#pull in df and group it by state, countyname and company name for additional planned analysis to add chart of most active companies
def company_grouped_df(start_date, end_date):
    d = {'NAME':['Reeves', 'Reeves', 'Reeves', 'Reeves', 'Reeves', 'Reeves', 'Harris', 'Burleson', 'Harris'], 
         'Company':['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'E'], 
         'Date':['12/1/2019', '12/2/2019', '12/1/2019', '12/2/2019', '12/3/2019','12/4/2019', '12/1/2019', '12/7/2019', '12/6/2019'], 
        'State':['TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX']}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df = df[df['Date'] >= start_date]
    df = df[df['Date'] <= end_date]
    df_grouped_co = df.groupby(['State', 'NAME', 'Company']).size().reset_index(name = 'Count')
    return df_grouped_co

#pull in county shapefiles. These are just the low res census shapefiles from data.gov downloaded to my drive
def county_shape_pull():
    mapfile = r"C:\County Shapefile\cb_2018_us_county_20m.shp"

    #create geopandas geodataframe
    map_df = gpd.read_file(mapfile)

    #delete unwanted counties to just get lower 48
    indexNames = map_df[map_df['STATEFP'] == '02'].index
    map_df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
    indexNames = map_df[map_df['STATEFP'] == '15'].index
    map_df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
    indexNames = map_df[map_df['STATEFP'] == '60'].index
    map_df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
    indexNames = map_df[map_df['STATEFP'] == '66'].index
    map_df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
    indexNames = map_df[map_df['STATEFP'] == '78'].index
    map_df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
    indexNames = map_df[map_df['STATEFP'] == '72'].index
    map_df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
    indexNames = map_df[map_df['STATEFP'] == '69'].index
    map_df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)

    #County shapefile has state FIPS while data has USPS code for each state so this table just creates x-ref
    #import table with state FP code and usps
    state_FP_code = pd.read_excel(r"C:\state fp to usps.xlsx")
    state_FP_code = state_FP_code.rename(columns={'st':'STATEFP'})
    map_df["STATEFP"] = pd.to_numeric(map_df["STATEFP"])

    #merge shapefile with state fp table to create key ID
    map_df = pd.merge(state_FP_code, map_df, how='left', on="STATEFP")
    map_df['NAME'] = map_df['NAME'].str.title()
    map_df = map_df.rename(columns={'stusps':'State'})
    return map_df

#this merges dataframe to geopandas dataframe with geomtry info
def merge_map_data(start_date, end_date):
    df = make_df(start_date, end_date)
    map_df = county_shape_pull()
    merged_subset = pd.merge(map_df, df,on=['NAME', 'State'], how='left')
    merged_subset['Count'].fillna(0, inplace = True)
    #merged_subset = merged_subset.dropna(subset=['Count'])
    merged_subset['CountyST'] = merged_subset['NAME'].astype(str) + ", " + (merged_subset['State'])
    merged_subset = merged_subset.loc[:, ['NAME', 'stname', 'CountyST', 'Count', 'geometry']]

    merged_subset['Detailed_Name'] = merged_subset['NAME'].astype(str) + ", " + (merged_subset['stname'])

    merged_subset = gpd.GeoDataFrame(merged_subset)


    merged_subset.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4269', 'no_defs': True}
    merged_subset = merged_subset[merged_subset.geometry.notnull()]

    merged_subset = merged_subset.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})

    return merged_subset

def make_plot(df):

    global geosource
    geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = df.to_json())

    # Define color palettes
    palette = brewer['Blues'][8]
    palette = palette[::-1] # reverse order of colors so higher values have darker colors

    # Instantiate LinearColorMapper that linearly maps numbers in a range, into a sequence of colors.
    color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 8)


    # Define custom tick labels for color bar.
    tick_labels_list = FixedTicker(ticks = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])


    # Create color bar.
    color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper = color_mapper, 
                         label_standoff = 8,
                         width = 500, height = 20,
                         border_line_color = None,
                         location = (0,0), 
                         orientation = 'horizontal',
                         ticker = tick_labels_list)

    # Create figure object.
    p = figure(title = 'Activity, US Counties', 
               plot_height = 800, plot_width = 1250,
               toolbar_location = 'below',
               tools = 'pan, wheel_zoom, reset') #_range=(-1100000, -6000000), y_range=(2500000, 4500000),
               #x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

    tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.CARTODBPOSITRON_RETINA)
    p.add_tile(tile_provider)


    counties = p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,
                       fill_color = {'field' :'Count',
                                     'transform' : color_mapper},
                                       line_color = 'gray', 
                                       line_width = 0.25, 
                                       fill_alpha = .5)
    # Create hover tool
    p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers = [counties],
                          tooltips = [('CountyST', '@CountyST'),
                                   ('Count', '@Count')]))


    #slider = DateRangeSlider(title="Date Range: ", 
                             #start=date(1999, 1, 1), 
                             #end=date.today(), 
                             #value=(date(2019, 1, 1), date.today()), 
                             #step=1)



    # Specify layout
    p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')
    p.axis.visible = False

    return p


#creates update function to update data based on slider but i believe something like this requires bokeh server as html doesn't know what to do with python
def update(attr, old, new):
    date_range_start = slider.value[0]
    date_range_end = slider.value[1]
    new_data_set = merge_map_data(date_range_start, date_range_end)
    merged_subset.data.update(new_data_set.data)
    return new_data_set.data

slider = DateRangeSlider(title="Date Range: ", 
                        start=date(1999, 1, 1), 
                        end=date.today(), 
                        value=(date(2019, 1, 1), date.today()), 
                        step=1)

slider.on_change('value', update)
src = merge_map_data(slider.value[0], slider.value[1])
p = make_plot(src)
controls = WidgetBox(slider)
layout = column(controls,p)
show(layout)
```
````

Comment: The Bokeh server is what causes `on_change` callbacks be triggered. You will need to embed a Bokeh server app in the notebook as  in the linked example in the other answer.

Comment: Bigreddot, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, my situation won’t allow me to use the Bokeh server given the work firewall so I’m thinking I need to resolve this with customJS. Is that a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: Definitely one option. if you only need to push out updates in response to widgets, and not get date like selections *back*, you might also look at `ipywidgets` plus Bokeh's `push_notebook`.